# Eevee vs. Cycles in camera

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, camera, eevee-render-engine

I would like to know how in Blender 2.90 do I set Cycles in Camera and Eevee for the rest.
This is due to render time of course.

Comment: my guess is you can't, it's one or the other